# Scene isn't filling screen when recreating gameScene to restart game

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

So I am working on a sprite kit game and in didContactBegin, I have:

```
SKScene* myScene =[[GameScene alloc]initWithSize:self.size];
SKTransition* reveal = [SKTransition doorwayWithDuration:.5];
reveal.pausesIncomingScene = YES;
[self.view presentScene:myScene transition:reveal];
```

This works almost perfectly except for the fact that it does not completely fill back up the screen as it did on its first run and everything is scaled a little smaller.  The x axis is completely filled but there seems to be a little bit missing on the top and bottom.

[image: before game restarts]
[image: after game restarts]

Why is it different?  It is the same code so shouldn't it do the same thing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set the scene's scale mode as you do when the view controller is first loaded:

```
SKScene* myScene =[[GameScene alloc]initWithSize:self.size];
myScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill; // Use here the value you used in the view controller when creating the scene for the first time
```